# Memory usage with xhr blob responseType (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, memory-management, xmlhttprequest, blob

Using Google Chrome, suppose I download a file as a blob using ajax as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'some/path', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {      
    //Save xhr.response using FileSystem API
};

xhr.send();
```

Do I need to worry about memory use here (assuming the file downloaded might be very large, or I might download lots of files in this way)?

My understanding is that since I'm specifying a responseType of 'blob' rather than 'arraybuffer', the downloaded data won't get loaded into the memory available to Javascript. However, the downloaded data must be stored somewhere. Is it just getting stored in memory, or will the browser put it in some kind of out-of-memory cache if necessary? If it is getting held in memory, is there any way for me to dispose of it once I'm done with it (i.e., in my example, once I've saved it using the FileSystem API).

Answer (score 2):

For binary or blob data, Chrome uses a complex system consisting of a memory buffer for the tab and an asynchronous global storage logic, which also swaps data to disk. There are limits on the tab memory, the global storage capacity, and importantly the speed at which data can be transferred between the two and swapped out.

This is not the same as the available JavaScript memory, which holds your code and regular variables.

There is no way of knowing exactly what those limits are, but the speed at which you create blobs plays a crucial role. Slowing down such operations to, say the speed of a slow disk, can greatly increase the memory available to your application.

An explanation of Chrome's Blob storage can be found here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/storage/browser/blob/README.md

To answer your question: Yes, you need to worry about memory there. If the data you're loading in your XHR request in one go is larger than the available tab memory, the tab will crash. Likewise, if you exceed the global storage allowance over time or load many smaller files too fast, you're also going to run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your specific question about where the data gets stored, but I would imagine it goes to memory on disk.

The part I can answer though, is how to free up the memory used by the blob object itself (not necessarily the data, just the blob object). As long as you are not using the object in your current scope or the scope has ended it will automatically be cleaned up. For example, inside a closure or anonymous function, when the function ends, anything that was created in that scope will be garbage collected. You can also manually assign it to null or call delete.

You should read about the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) from MDN.
There is also a [memory management page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Memory_Management) on MDN that explains the process above in much greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it goes to memory too. I recall something about chrome able to handle 800 MB of ram,  somewhere, unsure.

But i did a test on a ~1 GB movie and looked at the network tab. and most correctly it crashed when i saw the ~760 MB benchmark. So your best option would be to request chunks and append it to the filesystem

Answer (score 1):

The data is always stored in memory within a nsCString which dynamically grows by doubling. So an 260 MB File reserves up to ~512 MB memory. If you want to copy the response data into an arraybuffer, the memory peak increases up to 772 MB, because the arraybuffer (260MB) needs to be allocated, too.

The temporary 512 MB nsCString is hold, as long the XHR-object exists. So you have to set xhr=null, to garbage collect and free the memory. And of course many mobile systems have not much memory available and can crash due "out of memory". Some browsers-versions are memory-limited per Tab and crash already at 768MB memory usage.

There is a new [Fetch-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) out there, which allows chunk-based reading. Streaming the response body improves the memory usage. In XHR, the whole response would be buffered, rather than being able to operate on the data in chunks.